# Is that possible to get vscode version programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on a vscode extension, and would like to programmatically retrieve the host vscode's version in this extension. Is that possible? I knew there is an api to get other extensions version, `VSCode.extensions.getExtension('ext').packageJSON.version`, but is there a way to get vscode's version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the version of the editor, use `vscode.version`:

```ts
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

console.log(vscode.version); // "1.27.1"
```